# Xcode 11 test plans don't seem to localize the simulator status bar

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, screenshot, xctestplan

I use Xcode 11 test plans new feature to generate my localized screenshots for the app store. As explained during the WWDC19 you can use test plan configurations to play your UI tests generating screenshots in several languages.

Unfortunately it seems that it only specifies the languages and regions for the app, and not simulator-based.

For instance, when you use this configuration:

[image: French configuration]

The problem appears especially on iPad when the status bar displays the date:

[image: iPad with French app and English status bar]

So if someone knows how to force the simulator to update its language for each configuration, I would be grateful.

PS: I used to work with `fastlane/snapshot` but test plans are much more efficient (5 minutes generation instead of more than 40 with `fastlane`) so I'd rather not go back to `fastlane` if I can do otherwise.

Comment: Unfortunately no... :(

Comment: I found the answer right after posting my (now deleted) comment, I posted it here :)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that it's as simple as adding this to the setup:

```
app.launchArguments += ProcessInfo().arguments
```

But FWIW, I created [AspirinShot](https://twitter.com/AspirinShot) because this screenshot creation process was too annoying.